# handle ctrl+v in a multiline textbox c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, keyevent

I have a multiline textbox, and I'm trying to implement shortcut keys for select all, copy, paste, etc. (multiline seems to disable some of the native shortcuts). I have this code, inside a switch for KeyCode if on Control KeyDown.

```
case Keys.A:
    e.Handled = true;
    textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
    textBox3.SelectAll();
    break;
case Keys.C:
    e.Handled = true;
    if (textBox3.SelectedText.Length > 0)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(textBox3.SelectedText);
    }
    break;
case Keys.V:
    e.Handled = true;
    textBox3.Paste(Clipboard.GetText().Replace(Environment.NewLine, ""));
    break;
```

The first two work fine, but I can't suppress (Ctrl+V)'s normal actions (I want to strip newlines before pasting it). I have no idea what's causing this, so any ideas would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried **assgin** `textBox3.Text` instead of `Paste` method?

Comment: Are you sure you're suppressing the other keys' normal actions? Selection and copy could still take effect and you wouldn't notice as long as your code took place after. You need to intercept the key input before it reaches the control. Post a good [mcve] that shows what you've already got, explain what you've done so far and why you think it should work, and what _specifically_ you can't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a `PreviewKeyDown` handler, for all the same keys, that sets `e.IsInputKey` to true. Also, I had to add in `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;` in the normal keydown handler.